# Bitcoin multisignature addresses

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature, raw-transaction, regtest

Suppose we have a multisignature address "abc"  with 100 coins in bitcoin regtest network,  I want to that 100 coins in 10 slots that is i want spend 10 coins at a particular interval.

I tried the following:
At t1:

send 10 coins from "abc" to some address and a change returning 90 coins back to multisig "abc"

At t2:

send 10 coins from "abc" to some address and a change returning 80 coins back to multisig "abc"

and so on.

The step followed at time t1 worked perfectly but I am getting the below mentioned error while trying to do the step mentioned at time t2. That is , i am not able to spend again from the same multisig account.

```
error code: -25
error message:
Missing inputs
```

How can I spend multiple times from the same multisig address?

Comment: are you trying to spend the same inputs twice? How are you creating the transactions?

Comment: I am creating a new raw transaction by using the same tx id and vout that funded the multisig address(like i did it first time).

Comment: you can only use a specific txid and vout once. If you try to use it again, that input has already been used and it will result in a missing input error. For the 2nd tx try using the vout from the 90 coins that were returned.

Comment: I tried doing the same thing you mentioned but still I am getting the same error. @JBaczuk

Comment: Sorry without the transaction details its hard to help any further

Comment: I was using the wrong tx id (tx id without confirmation). Now its working. Thank You. @JBaczuk